# Cannot install requirements when bulding a docker image

Tags: python, docker, fedora

Trying to build a simple Django app in Docker and it worked on Fedora 31, but not on Fedora 32.

This is my Dockerfile, fairly simple:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY manage.py manage.py
# More COPYs

CMD [ "python" "./manage.py" "runserver" ]
```

However it fails on running pip install:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
after connection broken by 
'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6bbfda0280>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/asgiref/
```

I tried adding --dns params to docker like so:

```
--dns 10.252.252.252 --dns 10.253.253.253 --dns 8.8.8.8
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The error suggests a networking (proxying) issue rather than a Fedora issue.

`pip` pulls from `https://files.pythonhosted.org`.

- Can you ping this URL from the host?
- From within a docker container on the host?

I find it useful to manually run through Dockerfile commands when there are problems to try to identify the issue:

```sh
docker run --interactive --tty python:3 bash
```

Then:

```sh
PYPI="$(\
  curl \
  --silent \
  --write-out '%{http_code}\n' \
  --output /dev/null \
  https://files.pythonhosted.org)"
if [ "200" == "${PYPI}" ]
then
  echo "accessible"
else
  echo "inaccessible"
fi
```

If you want a single command:

```sh
docker run \
--interactive \
--tty \
python:3 \
  curl \
  --silent \
  --write-out '%{http_code}\n' \
  --output /dev/null \
  https://files.pythonhosted.org
```

That should confirm whether PyPi is accessible. Within the container (see above), you could then use something like the following to get more information on the `pip install`:

```sh
pip3 --verbose install flask
```

> **NOTE** replace `flask` with one of your packages

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can ping it from my machine, but not from inside the container. And pip install from inside the container produces the same errors as described in my original question.

Comment: Aha! Then, for some reason, it appears your machine is prohibiting outbound requests from containers. Unfortunately, I can't help explain why that is so (with Fedora 32) but it's possible there's been a change to networking security and this would be a good next step for you to explore.

Comment: I looked into firewalld log and it says
WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).

so you're right